# How can I remove rest of file from string for all files?

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I remove rest of file from string for all files?

For example, input files `1` and `2`, string is `ddd`.

Input file `1`.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddfbbd dddaaa
eee
```

Output file `1`.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddfbbd
```

Input file `2`.

```
ccc
aergddd
dasdvsdb
```

Output file `2`.

```
ccc
aerg
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```sh
str="ddd"
for file in 1 2; do
    sed -i "/$str/ {s/$str.*//; q}" "$file"
done
```

This needs to be in a loop: otherwise the `q` command would abort the whole process after processing only the first file.

Comment: Found it interesting you answered a similar question in Unix & LInux 8 years ago: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11323/200094

Comment: I wonder if you could just `d` instead of `q`

Comment: You're welcome to try. sed is not a go-to tool for me once things get more complicated that what I did.

Answer (score 7):

With Perl:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/ddd[\s\S]*//' file
```

or

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/ddd.*//s' file
```

- `-i`: modify the file in place.
- `-0777`: force Perl to slurp the file as whole, not line by line.
- `-pe`:

  - `-p`: loop Perl code.
  - `-e`: execute Perl code.
- `'s/ddd[\s\S]*//'`: replace everything (every whitespace (`\s`) and non-whitespace (`\S`) character) after `ddd` (including it) with an empty string.
- `'s/ddd.*//s'`: replace everything (`.*`) after `ddd` (including it) with an empty string. The `s` flag at the end makes `.*` also match newlines (thanks @glennjackman).

More about Perl flags can be found [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: Why not just `s/ddd.*//`?

Comment: @dessert `.*` stops matching at newline.

Comment: You can use.`.*` if you add the `m` or `s` flag to the `s///` command (I forget which one)

Comment: @glennjackman It's the `s` flag. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

with GNU `awk`, we can do:

```
awk 'function output(){ print >>FILENAME".out" }
     /ddd/{ sub(/ddd.*/,""); output(); nextfile }
          { output() }' file[12]
```

to change inplace, which it makes command even simple:

```
gawk -i inplace '/ddd/{ sub(/ddd.*/,""); print ; nextfile }1' file[12]
```